# Web interface for managing an ISC DHCP server

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

I am looking for a web interface to administer an ISC DHCP server. I have the setup of one Debian Linux box running an ISC DHCP server and I would like to add a second DHCP server as failover.

To facilitate administration for non-UNIX experienced users, I would like to run a web interface which can be used to add and change DHCP adresses with their corresponding MAC adresses. The DHCP server will be serving IP adresses based on the client's MAC adress.

Idealy it would also support synching the IP/MAC adress pairs to the second dhcp server, but this could be done with some scripting, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DHCPd module for webmin can do all that.

You can lock down webmin so specific users or groups can only access that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Try Zentyal.

http://doc.zentyal.org/en/dhcp.html

Debian Like Packages (ubuntu)

http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/Installation/InstallationGuide

[s]
Guto